# Camel CXF: one way scenario is accessing the user principal resulting in Null pointer exception

Tags: websphere-liberty, camel-cxf

Found this issue with Websphere Liberty profile 17.0.0.4. When I make a oneway request, this is resulting in a null pointer. It works fine with request-response services.

Mine is a spring boot app. The code works fine as a standalone springboot app running with an embedded tomcat container.

The error occurs when running inside Websphere liberty profile. I have disabled the embedded container whend deploying in WLP

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.collaborator.CollaboratorHelperImpl.getCurrentSecurityCollaborator(CollaboratorHelperImpl.java:286) ~[na:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.getUserPrincipal(SRTServletRequest.java:2796) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$2.getUserPrincipal(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:392) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.DefaultCxfBinding.populateExchangeFromCxfRequest(DefaultCxfBinding.java:274) ~[camel-cxf-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$CxfConsumerInvoker.prepareCamelExchange(CxfConsumer.java:316) ~[camel-cxf-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$CxfConsumerInvoker.syncInvoke(CxfConsumer.java:253) ~[camel-cxf-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$CxfConsumerInvoker.invoke(CxfConsumer.java:183) ~[camel-cxf-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[cxf-core-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by overriding the DefaultCxfBinding.I have disabled the creation of the securityContext for now. The CFX JMSConfig has an option of doing this by setting createSecurityContext as false. Even the HTTP transport should have this feature

@Override
public void populateExchangeFromCxfRequest(Exchange cxfExchange, org.apache.camel.Exchange camelExchange) {

```
Message cxfMessage = cxfExchange.getInMessage();    
cxfMessage.put(SecurityContext.class, null);        
super.populateExchangeFromCxfRequest(cxfExchange, camelExchange);
```

}